# How to pull data formatted for Matlab into R?

Tags: r, matlab

I just ran a vendor-supplied program that converts data from their proprietary binary format to what they call a "Matlab format". There are two resulting files from the conversion, a "filename.dat" and a "filename.m".

The "filename.m" file seems to have column heading information in it. The second "filename.dat" file is >13Gigs in size and I can't load it into anything at the moment to inspect it.

How do I go about loading this "Matlab format" data into R?

Comment: You can use EmEditor to open large files.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't sound like "Matlab format" (which would be a .mat file).

Rather, the .m-file is a Matlab function or script that is most likely used to read the data in the .dat file.

Have a look at the Matlab [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/) to find out how the .m file reads the data, so that you can port the code to R.

Answer (score 2):

The R package [R.matlab](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.matlab/index.html) can read .mat files. I use it to store 3D arrays from Python and then use them in R. Basically 3D arrays become lists of 2D arrays in R; also variable names get imported and you can call them from the data.frame.

However, see Jonas' answer that your data is not real Matlab format .mat yet.